# Show only user registered communities in the "StackExchange" dropdown in header

Tags: feature-request, top-bar, header

I have been using the stackoverflow and recently I registered in a some other stackExchange communities like drupal, unix & Linux, computing sciences, cognitive sciences. If suppose I'm in stackoverflow and suddenly if I want to open one of my communities (computing sciences) I don't find my communities in the drop down.

Again I need to open new tab and give my link -- it's rather hectic.

So, I suggest you to add only the user registered communities in the "stackexchange" dropdown in header rather than all the communities of stackexchange. This will definitely improve the flexibility of registered communities.

Hope you do consider my suggestion and improve our site.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On any Stack Exchange site ***except*** https://stackexchange.com/, the StackExchange dropdown menu has a blue "Edit" button to the right of YOUR COMMUNITIES, if you are logged in:

[image]

Clicking it allows you to select what sites should appear on your dropdown:

[image]

Your screen-shot is from https://stackexchange.com/, which for whatever reason does not have this edit capability.

Comment: Yaa i got it, unfortunately I didn't come acroos that edit button

Comment: Area 51, chat, and stackexchange.com are all separate codebases and they grab the site switcher (and other topbar dialogs) from Q&A sites through an internal API. We opted not to build API calls for the editor largely for simplicity's sake.